# How to handle whitespace between tokens in an antlr3 grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr3

I have a question about whitespace handling in an antlr3 grammar.  Here's a stripped-down version of the grammar:

```
grammar SLiMScript;

inputFile   :
        NEWLINE*
        sectionOutput?
        ;

sectionOutput   :   '#OUTPUT' NEWLINE+ outputLine+ ;
outputLine  :   (output_all) NEWLINE+ ;
output_all  :   NUMBER 'A' STRING? ;

NEWLINE :   ('\r'? '\n') ;

NUMBER :        ('0' | (DIGIT_1 DIGIT_0*)) ('.' DIGIT_0*)? EXPONENT? ;
fragment EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? DIGIT_0+ ;
fragment DIGIT_0    :   '0'..'9' ;
fragment DIGIT_1    :   '1'..'9' ;

STRING :    '"' (~('"'|'\n'|'\r'|'\\'))* '"' ;

WS  :       ( ' ' | '\t' ) { skip(); } ;
```

And here's a simple input file:

```
#OUTPUT 
1000 A "foo bar baz"
```

In general, I want whitespace to get stripped out; thus, the whitespace rule at the end of the grammar.  However, I do want whitespace to be required between tokens.  For example, if you look at the output file, I don't want `1000A"foo"` to be legal; I want spaces between the tokens to be required.  Having to explicitly specify that everywhere in the grammar would be pretty painful, though.  And I can't have my cake and eat it too; if I keep my whitespace-stripping, rule, then I can't change my statement rule to:

```
output_all  :   NUMBER WS 'A' (WS STRING)? ;
```

because the whitespace tokens have already gotten stripped at that point; there's no whitespace left for the rule to match.  Maybe I have no choice except to get rid of the implicit whitespace-stripping and instead put a `WS` reference between every single pair of tokens in the whole grammar, to get the behavior I want.  But surely there's a better way...?

How do languages like C do it?  You can write `static int foo` but you can't write `staticintfoo`; why not?  How do grammars for such languages force whitespace between tokens like that?  I'm guessing it's because `staticintfoo` gets tokenized as an identifier, presumably because that rule comes first; that string would also match the tokens `static`, `int`, and (identifier) `foo`, but before that can happen, they get gobbled up as a single big identifier, and that causes an error since that identifier is not defined.  Is there a way to do something similar in my situation?  To implicitly require whitespace between tokens by making the whitespace-free version cause an alternative interpretation that leads to an error?  I'm not really seeing a graceful way to do it.

I've read Parr's books Language Implementation Patterns and The Definitive ANTLR Reference, and I more or less understand them I think, but I feel like I'm lacking a good review of how to actually design a practical grammar for various specific applied situations.  Some kind of book like The Art of LL(*) Grammar Design.  Is there such a book out there?

Comment: The way your C example works is that lexers tend to eat the largest possible string that matches a token.  So `staticintfoo` is an identifier, not the three tokens, "static", "int", "foo".  The error message will then be that `staticintfoo` is an undeclared identifier, not that there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better way. Either you want the whitespaces to get stripped out or not. You cannot get wet and stay dry at the same time.

If you really want to enforce whitespaces between (certain) tokens then you have to take in WS everywhere, no way around that. Though, I question your intention. Usually it works very well to simply ignore whitespaces, except for some very weirdly defined lanugages like Python or FORTRAN where indentation is part of the language.

As a workaround, and only if you have very specific cases you want to avoid (like `1000A`), you could define a lexer rule that matches specifically this input and let it return a token that is nowhere valid, causing a syntax error in the parser.